# href's onclick breaks after other href is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using `jquery mobile` in a cordova app.

I have multiple links (jquery mobile buttons), some of which follow a normal  `href` link, others call some code in `onclick`.

When pressing my buttons making use of `onclick`, they work for multiple presses  . I can press them multiple times, each time envoking the code.

However, when I press on of my buttons with a normal `href` link, my buttons making use of `onclick` seems to break. The moment I press a button following a normal `href` link, my other `onclick` buttons stop working.

It is worth noting that my buttons making use of `onclick`, also *NEVER* shows the "pressed" animation that jquery mobile adds when clicked. The normal `href` buttons *ALWAYS* shows the "pressed" animation when clicked.

My links all navigate to outside of the app, either activating an intent, or navigating to an external website using `InAppBrowser`. The normal `href` buttons always works.

I have tried to reload the page in place when a button is clicked, but this does not work.

```
 $("#ctel").on('click', function (e) {

      $.mobile.changePage("#businessCard");

 });
```

My links:

```
<a href="tel:x" id="ctel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-phone ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"></a>
<a href="mailto:x" id="cmail" class="ui-btn ui-icon-mail ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"></a>
<a href="#" id="cbookings" class="ui-btn ui-icon-calendar ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" onclick="window.open('link', '_system');"></a>
<a href="#" id="cwebsite" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" onclick="window.open('link', '_system');"></a>
```

Comment: ... detailed explanation of your problem would be great. What does stop working? The function behind that button? Please provide a fiddle on which we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I thought I was being exceptionally detailed :-) The actual `onclick` code stops firing, I.e. I cant navigate to external links when pressing the button.

Comment: Can you reproduce this inside a fiddle? You first press an `a` and after that your `onclick` can not be pressed anymore?

Comment: No fiddle, the code uses jquery mobile, themes for the buttons etc. See my different <a> buttons. SOme uses href, some uses onclick. Using href, breaks the onclick ones.

Comment: You can simply add jQuery Mobile to your fiddle. This isn't a normal behaviour of jQuery nor jquery mobile. There has to be an issue inside your codebase.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with inApBrowser, but I unfortunately cant add the whole cordova project with plugins to a fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81966/discussion-between-sithys-and-louis-van-tonder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sithys was suggesting, I actually did have an error not relating directly to the jquery mobile buttons. I was re-writing my url's to point to another stats url, from which it then redirected to the appropriate url.

It seems some of the intents did not like this redirect, and probably caused an undesired effect/error somewhere in the android/cordova eco system. I removed the stats url, and by implication the redirect to the intent, and all is working as it should.

Strangely, I did however test this in Ripple emulator, and there it works perfectly fine with the stats tracking url and redirect.

I ended up doing a manual ajax post to track my clicks, and just activated the intents as per normal.